# FriendlyID - use default IDs in admin namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I've installed [FriendlyID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) on my rails app. I've followed the instructions on this issue https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/700 and changed my links like this according to the 1st option.

```
# before: admin_post_path(@post)
link_to admin_post_path(@post.id)
```

So far so good, however when I try to submit the _form I get the following error

`Couldn't find Post with 'id'=hello-world`

After some debugging I have found that this was occured because I had also removed the .friendly method from the Post.find, so:

```
def set_post
   # before: Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

so when I put it back in everything was working. However this generates one extra query which is used for getting the slugs, as you know

```
Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`slug` = '1' LIMIT 1
Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Now here's my question: Is there a way to keep the `@post = Post.find(params[:id])` on `set_post` and remove this extra query? Keep in mind that I want this to apply ONLY on Admin namespace, so on frontend the links should work using the friendly id and slugs

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing two queries because that's how FriendlyId's `find` method is designed to work. For numeric strings, it will first do a friendly find, and then fall back to a regular find.

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb#L18) (and the excellent comments), you can see that there is a way around this - we can make the `id` "unfriendly".

[Here's a list of things](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/object_utils.rb) which are considered "unfriendly". In this case, you can drop the extra query by turning `params[:id]` into an integer value yourself:

```
def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id].to_i)
end
```

Alternatively, you can also use the explicit `find_by` method on `:id` - which should skip the FriendlyId finder methods altogether.

Comment: Isn't the problem with the generated link, not with the lookup itself? I mean, the slug is used in the link instead of the actual id? The error the op gets is `Couldn't find Post with 'id'=hello-world`

Comment: @Iceman: hmm, not as far as I understand. Otherwise you wouldn't be seeing `slug = '1'` coming through in the logs, but the slug value instead...

Comment: No, you're right it seems, just a thought. I had a similar problem with friendly_id a while back.

Comment: The links seem to work fine, the issue occurs when trying to submit a form